# Servlet Redirect Only After Clicking JavaScript Alert Message

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am trying to redirect my servlet to some page only after clicking JavaScript alert message but its redirecting to the page without showing the alert message.

```
if(!rs.next()){

out.println("<script>confirm('Record Not Found!');</script>");
request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchDriver.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not redirect to RecordNotFound.jsp which only contains these scripts.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  alert('Record Not Found!');
  top.window.location = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/SearchDriver.jsp';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is getting executed at server side. It is printing your code with script tag and then moving to next statement which redirects you to SearchDriver.jsp

**Solution**: implement it using MVC pattern. Move your js into jsp and redirect to SearchDriver.jsp from js, using

> window.Location= yourJspPath